# Usando ajax, Cómo abrir paginas php, desde otra php que tiene el menu principal con nav usando

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, div

por favor, estoy usando ajax para abrir paginas php desde la que tengo el menu (hecho con nav "index.php").

Las paginas no las tengo necesariamente en la misma carpeta que index.php; por lo que pienso que es el problema que tengo, dado que con btn1 sí me funciona, pero con btn2.

**Aquí el código del script en index.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/registrar_pago.php",
            success: function(response) {
                $('#contenidos_externos').html(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#btn2').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/php/cobranza/registrar_nc.php",
            success: function(response) {
                $('#contenidos_externos').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Aquí las opciones del menú**:

```
<li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-coin-euro"></span>Cobranza<span class="caret icon-arrow-down6"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a id="btn1">Registrar Pagos<span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
                        <!--<li><a id="btn1" href="registrar_pago.php">Registrar Pagos<span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>-->
                        <li><a id="btn2">Notas/Crédito  <span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="php/Cobranza/registrar_nd.php">Notas/Débito   <span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="exportar_pdf/reportepagosdia.php">Consultar   <span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="php/Cobranza/registrar_aviso.php">Registrar Aviso <span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

**Aquí el div (en index.php) donde deseo que aparezca el contendido de las paginas**:

```
   </nav>

    <div id="contenidos_externos">           
    </div>
</div>

</header>
```

**Espero puedan entenderlo,
Saludos**

Comment: Si presionas el btn2 primero y luego el btn1, ¿el btn2 funciona?

Comment: Hola @KevinDelva, ya lo logré. Aparentemente al cambiar el nombre de la carpeta Cobranza a cobranza hizo que se solucionara.

Comment: Ahora @KevinDelva, quisiera saber si peuedes ayudarme con otra cosa cuando abre los php en <div id="contenidos_externos">. Qué sucede? me cambia la fuente del menu nav de la pagina principal, al darle al boton salir del php que llamo, vuelve a su fuente original.

Comment: la fuente la tienes en el body, css o header?

Comment: @KevinDelva la fuente del menu la tengo en un archivo css linkeado desde el head